# Passing a list that includes a nested list of datetimes on command execution not working in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rather strange requirement for a Wpf Project I'm working on. I want to be able to build a XamDataGrid with a series of DateTime fields when the user saves the data from another grid. Currently I see the second XamDataGrid with it's fields, but upon execution of the command that saves the data, although I can see in the debugger that my second list (which is bound to the second XamDataGrid) is generated, nothing displays on this second XamDataGrid.

I'll post most of my code so that somebody might help me:

The xaml (for the second datagrid as the first one is working fine):

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:Field Label="ID" Name="id" Width="50"></igDP:Field>
                    <igDP:Field Label="Descripcion" Name="descripcion" Width="400"></igDP:Field>
                    <igDP:UnboundField Label="Fechas de Pago" Name="cadaPago" Width="400">     
                    </igDP:UnboundField>
                    <igDP:Field Label="Colores" Name="Colores" Visibility="Collapsed"  />
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

`

The code in my viewmodel for the second grid:

```
 public List<ClaseFechasPago> ListaFechasPago
        {
            get { return listaFechasPago; }
            set { listaFechasPago = value; notifyChanges("ListaFechasPago"); }
        }

public void PintarFechas(List<ClaseFechasPago> f)
    {

        ListaFechasPago.Clear();

        foreach (ClaseFechasPago fecha in f)
        {
            fecha.cadaPago = new List<DateTime>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fecha.numPagos; i++)
            {
                fecha.cadaPago.Add(new DateTime());
            }
            ListaFechasPago.Add(fecha);
        }
    }

    public vmCursos_y_Diplomados()
    {
        Comando = new cmdCursos_y_Diplomados();
        Comando.ViewModel = this;
        ListaCursosyDiplomados = new List<ClaseCursosyDiplomados>();
        ListaFechasPago = new List<ClaseFechasPago>();
        this.cargarDatos();
        this.PintarFechas(ListaFechasPago);
    }
```

Now on the command I'm doing the following

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        List<CatEntidadesEducacionContinua> cursos = new List<CatEntidadesEducacionContinua>();
        List<ClaseFechasPago> fechas = new List<ClaseFechasPago>();

        foreach (ClaseCursosyDiplomados C in ViewModel.ListaCursosyDiplomados.Where(t=>t.Colores==1).ToList())
        {
            cursos.Add(new CatEntidadesEducacionContinua
            {
             IdEntidadEducacionContinua = C.id, Coordinador=C.coordinador, Descripcion=C.descripcion, FechaUltimoCambio = DateTime.Now,
             FechaInicio = C.fechaInicio, FechaTermino=C.fechaTermino, Precio=C.precio, NumeroDePagos=C.numeroDePagos, FechasPagos=C.fechasPagos, Inhabilitado=C.inhabilitado,
            });
            if (C.numeroDePagos > 1)
            {
                ClaseFechasPago f = new ClaseFechasPago();
                f.numPagos = C.numeroDePagos;
                f.descripcion = C.descripcion;
                f.id = C.id;
                fechas.Add(f);
            }

        }

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(new Entidades.MetodoCursos_y_Diplomados().SetEntidadEContinua(cursos), "Entidades de Educación Continua", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information);
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(new Entidades.MetodoFechasPago().pintarFechasPago
        ViewModel.cargarDatos();
        ViewModel.PintarFechas(fechas);
    }
```

But as I said it's not working, the execution results in the following screenshot, where the second grid is not populated:

[image: XamDataGrid not filled]

Oh and I also forgot earlier to show the code for my custom class, out of which the list bound to the XamDataGrid is made of:

```
public class ClaseFechasPago : Utils.PropertyChange
{
    private List<DateTime> _cadaPago;

    public List<DateTime> cadaPago
    {
        get { return _cadaPago; }
        set
        {
            _cadaPago = value;
            if (EntroPrimeraVez)
            {
                Colores = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    private int? _numPagos;

    public int? numPagos
    {
        get { return _numPagos; }
        set
        {
            _numPagos = value;

            if (EntroPrimeraVez)
            {
                Colores = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    private int _id;

    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    private string _descripcion;

    public string descripcion
    {
        get { return _descripcion; }
        set { _descripcion = value; }
    }

    private int _Colores;
    private bool _EntroPrimeraVez;
    public bool EntroPrimeraVez
    {
        get { return _EntroPrimeraVez; }
        set { _EntroPrimeraVez = value; notifyChanges("EntroPrimeraVez"); }
    }

    public int Colores
    {
        get { return _Colores; }
        set { _Colores = value; notifyChanges("Colores"); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the only thing I needed to do was passing the List explicitly as a list, like so:
 `ListaFechasPago = ListaFechasPago.ToList()` 
However, I seemed to have a mistake of concept in the way I was building the date fields. I ended up building as many registries as were needed of the same entry and binding a DateTime field to each, like so:

```
public static List<ClaseFechasPago> PintarFechas(ClaseFechasPago f)
    {

        List<ClaseFechasPago> ListaFechasPago = new List<ClaseFechasPago>();

        for (int i = 0; i < f.numPagos; i++)
        {

            ClaseFechasPago fecha = new ClaseFechasPago();

            fecha.cuotaInscripcion = 0M;
            fecha.Inscripcion = true;
            fecha.fechaPago = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
            fecha.id = f.id;
            fecha.descripcion = f.descripcion;
            fecha.numPagos = f.numPagos;
            fecha.Colores = f.Colores;
            fecha.EntroPrimeraVez = f.EntroPrimeraVez;
            ListaFechasPago.Add(fecha);
        }

        return ListaFechasPago;
        //ListaFechasPago = ListaFechasPago.ToList();
    }
```

Oh and of course initialize the ListaFechasPago List in the class that is set as DataContext for the window:

`ListaFechasPago = new List<ClaseFechasPago>();`

insde the class `vmCursos_y_Diplomados`

because I do:

```
 private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new vmCursos_y_Diplomados();
    }
```